# grid command in F# Interactive window

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

So I installed F# and I'm running VS 2008. I'm following along on a video tutorial the microsoft guys put on awhile ago.  At one point, he wants to throw his output to a grid window and types

```
grid prices;;
```

this produces an error for me:

C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Local Settings\Temp\stdin(3,1): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'grid' is not defined

Am I missing something?  Is this a feature of VS 2010 only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you watching [a video by Luca Bolognese](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/pdc2008/tl11)? If so, he is using a component he got from somewhere, which off the top of my head I believe is these guys:

http://www.ffconsultancy.com/dotnet/fsharp/

I remember something about being able to get a free version if you email them.

Comment: I should also say that I think in the video he mentions where he got it.

Comment: ok, thanks for the update. Ah, didn't realise he gave the source. Luca is fantastic, isn't he? :)

Comment: He is, I thoroughly enjoyed the tutorial.  For those interested, you can find it here:

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/